# Non-ssl API: Registration and subsequent authentication

Tags: rest, security, authentication

I am building an api for my first app, which consists of both a web based app grafted onto an existing website, and a mobile Cordova app. I am still something of a noob to concepts of authentication and security, so I am just trying to get an idea of the basics, and want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious. So far here's what I've got:

**The server currently is non-ssl.** I am registering users by making a `POST` request to the API with the plain text username and password appended as form data. An api key is then generated for the user which is returned to them, which they will then use for subsequent requests by including it in the header.

OK, so... given that this app isn't handling particularly sensitive data, and I only really care about basic-level security, is this acceptable? Is there any obvious and simple step I could take to improve the above setup?

Thanks.